# How to redirect 301 bad url?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have bad url:

```
http://mypage.org/first/second/?one=two&three=3&44=1
```

and i want this redirect to:

```
http://mypage.org
```

but in htaccess:

```
Redirect 301 /first/second/?one=two&three=3&44=1 http://mypage.org
```

not working. For example:

```
Redirect 301 /first/second http://mypage.org
```

working ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check query string with `mod_rewrite`

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^one=two&three=3&44=1$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^first/second/$ /? [R=301,L]
```